# Trying to implement a method that can compare any two lists but it always returns false

Tags: c#, list, comparison, ienumerable

I'm trying to make a method that can compare any two lists for equality. I'm trying to compare them in a way that validates that every element of one list has the same value as every element of another list. My `Equals` method below always returns `false`, can anyone see why that is?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class IEnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<x.Count();i++){
          if(!Object.Equals(x.ElementAt(i), y.ElementAt(i))){
             return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;

        return unchecked(obj
            .Select(e => e.GetHashCode())
            .Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + b)); 
    }
}
```

Here is my data I'm using to test this `Equals` method:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car car1 = new Car();
            car1.make = "Toyota";
            car1.model = "xB";

            Car car2 = new Car();
            car2.make = "Toyota";
            car2.model = "xB";

            List<Car> l1 = new List<Car>();
            List<Car> l2 = new List<Car>();
            l1.Add(car1);
            l2.Add(car2);

           IEnumerableComparer<Car> seq = new IEnumerableComparer<Car>();

           bool b = seq.Equals(l1, l2);

           Console.Write(b); //always says false
           Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Car class:

```
   class Car
    {
        public String make { get; set; }
        public String model { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @TylerPfaff it is not possible to check any two objects for equality. How would you check instances of `WinForms.Button` or `FileStream` for equality? You need to define what *equality* means for you. Properties equal? Fields equal? What about recursive objects? Cycles? Case-sensitivity for strings?

Comment: Your GetHashCode does not need the *unchecked* and *aggregate*. Just obj.GetHashCode() would suffice.

Comment: @usr I see, sorry I read your comment as trying to compare objects of type `Button` and `FileStream` to each other.

Comment: @usr: Fundamentally, `x.Equals(y)` asks the object identified by `x` whether *reference* `y` identifies an equivalent object, a question most objects would have no problem answering unambiguously for most particular definitions of equivalence.  Even an object x which would not consider itself equivalent to any other object in the universe should have no problem answering `x.Equals(y)`: it should return true if and only if reference `y` identifies it.  The only ambiguities in `Equals` revolve around the proper meaning of equivalence.

Comment: @supercat you can contrive an Equals that works for any type: just delegate to object.ReferenceEquals. That always works, but is not always useful. Even a basic type like string has at least 6 different comparers built into the framework. What's the "right" one? Depends on the use case. You cannot build a comparer that works for any two objects and is always useful at the same time.

Comment: @usr: I would posit that 99% of the time when something needs to compare two references and doesn't have particular knowledge of the types involved, one of two questions will be appropriate.  If each of the two references identifies an object to which only one other entity will ever hold a reference, the question should be "Assuming nobody has persisted identity-related hash values, would swapping *all* references to you with references to X (and vice versa) observably change the program state?".  If the references are sharable, the question should be...

Comment: ..."Would changing some references to you into references to X, or vice versa, be expected to change program state"?  In most cases, the object holding a reference will know which situation applies.  There are certainly cases like String where multiple styles of comparison may be appropriate, but in such cases the owner of the objects being compared will know what the objects are and what they mean (note receipt of an explicitly-specified `IEqualityComparer` would give the recipient "particular knowledge of the types involved").

Comment: I rather err on the side of making things undefined than picking defaults that turn out to be a surprise a few cases. For that reason I think object should not have a virtual Equals method at all. I understand and respect your position. We should agree to disagree regarding this issue.

Comment: @usr: As I see it, if one creates a `Dictionary<Button,SupplementalButtonInfo>`, there's a clear and logical way for such a thing to behave.  As such, even if `Button` has no sensible meaning for equality other than reference equality, there's no reason not to allow such a dictionary.  If `Object` didn't have a virtual `Equals` member, it would be hard to allow one dictionary type to be used in cases which required `ReferenceEquals` and cases which required a value-related `Equals`.

Comment: @supercat I'd base equality, hashcodes and comparison entirely on interfaces. In case where no such interface is found at runtime I'd error out. In the example you just gave I'd be fine with the fact that I probably have to init the dict with a ReferenceEqualityComparer manually. I hate implicit behavior that has a chance for surprises.

Comment: @usr: I dislike surprises too, but having a universal virtual equivalence relation is useful.  Perhaps the real problem is the name.  If it were called something like `EquivalentTo`, the fact that `list1.Equivalent(list2)` returns false when the the references identify different mutable lists containing the same items would be less surprising, since `list1.Add(x)` and `list2.Add(x)` would have different effects.  Such behavior would also allow mutable types to define `Equals` to refer to value equality without muddying up the meaning of the virtual equivalence relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default version of [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) compares references (for reference types). There are three possible solutions to your problem:

- override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for the `Car` class
- add another version of `IEnumerableComparer<T>` constructor accepting [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IEqualityComparer.aspx) which will be used to compare individual instances and provide its implementation for each use case
- use only value types, as for them the default version of [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will behave as you expect. Note that all fields and properties of these value types will have to conform to the 1st or 3rd option given here (i.e. either have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overridden or be a value type also). It's not really a recommended solution in general, I just mention it as a theoretical possibility. In your case it would help though - try changing `class Car` to `struct Car`.

Also, as correctly pointed out by wageoghe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883453/2642204) you can use the [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of writing your own implementation, but still you need to comply to one of the solutions given above (using this [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload for the second option).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not use SequenceEqual?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Bool b = l1.SequenceEqual(l2);
```

Note that the objects in the sequences still must implement Equals and GetHashCode correctly.

Comment: This is essentially what the OP already has.  `SequenceEquals` calls `Object.Equals` under the covers.  He'll still suffer from reference inequality.

Comment: He has what amounts to a very bad implementation of SequenceEquals. Why reimplement it? If he wants to reimplement, don't use Count() and ElementAt(x) (twice).

Answer (score 1):

Give your car the overrides as well:

```
class Car
{
    public String make { get; set; }
    public String model { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Car;
        return (other != null) 
                && (this.make == other.make) 
                && (this.model == other.model); 
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return make.GetHashCode() ^ model.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```